# Identify row pattern in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this peculiar situation where I get some rows similar to the following, this comes from some integration operation I can't control.

Please use this script to replicate

```
CREATE TABLE #SOMETABLE 
(
  FIELD VARCHAR,
  VALUE INT
)

INSERT INTO #SOMETABLE
(FIELD,VALUE)
VALUES
('A',1),
('B',3),
('C',5),

('A',90),
('B',15),
('C',21),

('A',31),
('B',75),
('C',82)

SELECT * FROM #SOMETABLE
```

You'll get

[image]

As you can see A-B-C pattern repeats itself and it's guaranteed to repeat in that order, so I need to identify these "groups" of rows with an extra calculated column (GROUP).

So it must end like this

[image]

I have tried several lame attempts, searched google, read articles here and there, but I'm not even sure what terms to use for a google search, [it does seem that SQL Server can identify patterns in rows](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/04/t-sql-queries/row-pattern-recognition-in-sql), but I'm not sure where to start

So my question is: How to identify groups of rows in SQL Server 2014?

**EDIT**

It's hard to elaborate, but I can tell there's a unique ID field, and there's a "Position" field that guarantees the order of all ABC's

```
CREATE TABLE #SOMETABLE 
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 FK_FIELD_NAME VARCHAR,
 [VALUE] INT,
 [FK_FIELD_POSITION] INT
)

INSERT INTO #SOMETABLE
(ID,FK_FIELD_NAME,[VALUE],[FK_FIELD_POSITION])
VALUES
(1,'A',1,17),
(2,'B',3,18),
(3,'C',5,19),

(4,'A',90,17),
(5,'B',15,18),
(6,'C',21,19),

(7,'A',31,17),
(8,'B',75,18),
(9,'C',82,19)

SELECT * FROM #SOMETABLE
```

[image]

Comment: Will it always be a group of the same number of rows? In this case, three?

Comment: And how do you determine that ('A',90) is in group 2, while ('A',31) is in group 3, when tables have no intrinsic order?

Comment: @BJones yes, same number

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This data comes from another query which has an "order by" clause, I can't control this query though

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  You need to have some columns to ORDER BY to make this work in TSQL.

Comment: Sorry to say,  but you need an extra column in that table first. For example:  `CREATE TABLE #SOMETABLE 
(
 ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 FIELD VARCHAR(30),
 VALUE INT
);`  The point is that you need something to order by, something that corresponds with the order the records were inserted.

Comment: Does the result set you're analyzing include the column(s) referenced by the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: @LukStorms There is a PK, I didn't include it, I didn't think it was relevant, I was wrong

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'll elaborate

Comment: @TheOne, I re-posted

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sorry, we order by the ID field, there's also a related "Field Position" field, that determines the order of A-B-C (if relevant)

Comment: Can you add all that to your repro script, so it can be incorporated in answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonably general way to solve this problem is to count the number of times the `FK_FIELD_POSITION` decreases, in a ordering by `(ID,FK_FIELD_POSITION)`.

EG

```
drop table if exists #SOMETABLE
go
CREATE TABLE #SOMETABLE 
(
ID INT  PRIMARY KEY,
 FK_FIELD_NAME VARCHAR,
 [VALUE] INT,
 [FK_FIELD_POSITION] INT
)

INSERT INTO #SOMETABLE
(ID,FK_FIELD_NAME,[VALUE],[FK_FIELD_POSITION])
VALUES
(1,'A',1,17),
(2,'B',3,18),
(3,'C',5,19),

(4,'A',90,17),
(5,'B',15,18),
(6,'C',21,19),

(7,'A',31,17),
(8,'B',75,18),
(9,'C',82,19);

with q as
(
SELECT *, case when fk_field_position < LAG(fk_field_position) over (order by id,fk_field_position) then 1 else 0  end groupStart
FROM #SOMETABLE
)
select *, 1+sum(groupStart) over (order by id) groupNum
from q
```

Outputs

```
ID          FK_FIELD_NAME VALUE       FK_FIELD_POSITION groupStart  groupNum
----------- ------------- ----------- ----------------- ----------- -----------
1           A             1           17                0           1
2           B             3           18                0           1
3           C             5           19                0           1
4           A             90          17                1           2
5           B             15          18                0           2
6           C             21          19                0           2
7           A             31          17                1           3
8           B             75          18                0           3
9           C             82          19                0           3

(9 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Before adding to the temp table add a autoincrement to the table and VOILA:

```
DROP TABLE #SOMETABLE
CREATE TABLE #SOMETABLE 
(
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 FIELD VARCHAR,
 VALUE INT
)

INSERT INTO #SOMETABLE
(    FIELD,VALUE)
VALUES
('A',1),
('B',3),
('C',5),

('A',90),
('B',15),
('C',21),

('A',31),
('B',75),
('C',82)

SELECT *, ceiling(ID/3.0) FROM #SOMETABLE
```

Comment: This is the simplest and therefore the best answer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest, easiest way is to iterate over the rows using a cursor:

```
create table #sometable2
(
    field varchar,
    [value] int,
    [group] int
)

declare @field char(1)
declare @value int
declare @group int = 1

declare something_cursor cursor for 
select field, [value] from #sometable

open something_cursor  
fetch next from something_cursor into @field, @value 

while @@fetch_status = 0  
begin  
      insert into #sometable2 select @field, @value, @group 

      if @field = 'C' set @group = (select @group + 1)

      fetch next from something_cursor into @field, @value
end 

close something_cursor  
deallocate something_cursor

select * from #sometable2
```

Result:

```
╔═══════╤═══════╤═══════╗
║ field │ value │ group ║
╠═══════╪═══════╪═══════╣
║ A     │ 1     │ 1     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ B     │ 3     │ 1     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ C     │ 5     │ 1     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ A     │ 90    │ 2     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ B     │ 15    │ 2     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ C     │ 21    │ 2     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ A     │ 31    │ 3     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ B     │ 75    │ 3     ║
╟───────┼───────┼───────╢
║ C     │ 82    │ 3     ║
╚═══════╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Comment: Now cue the chorus of voices saying how inefficient it is to use a cursor to do this. Arguably true. I think it clearly depends on the number of rows. And the cursor does have the advantage of being easy to read and understand. So, take this answer with a "grain of salt."

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to add another ID column? Or perhaps a ROW_NUMBER() window function.

```
CREATE TABLE #SOMETABLE 
(
 ID INT,
 FIELD VARCHAR,
 VALUE INT
)

INSERT INTO #SOMETABLE
(ID,FIELD,VALUE)
VALUES
(1,'A',1),
(2,'B',3),
(3,'C',5),

(4,'A',90),
(5,'B',15),
(6,'C',21),

(7,'A',31),
(8,'B',75),
(9,'C',82)

SELECT t.*
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID % 3 ORDER BY t.ID) rn
FROM #SOMETABLE t
ORDER BY t.ID
```

Or if you can't have the ID field added... I don't guarantee this:

```
SELECT t2.*
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.ID % 3 ORDER BY t2.ID) rn
FROM(
     SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ID
     FROM #SOMETABLE t
    )t2
ORDER BY t2.ID
```

Comment: If there are gaps in the ID, that won't work.  But this should: `row_number() over (partition by field order by ID) as GroupNumber`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Are you considering to post an answer?

Comment: Yes, see above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that considers 'A' as the first in a serie.
Then assigns the same rank to non-'A' after it.

Which also means that this method still works if 'D' or 'E' or whatever isn't 'A' follows it.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #SOMETABLE 
> (
>  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>  FIELD VARCHAR(30),
>  VALUE INT
> );
> INSERT INTO #SOMETABLE
> (FIELD,VALUE)
> VALUES
> ('A',1), ('B',3), ('C',5),
> ('A',90),('B',15),('C',21),
> ('A',31),('B',75),('C',82);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 9 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> , SUM(CASE WHEN FIELD='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
>     OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Rnk
> FROM #SOMETABLE
> ORDER BY ID
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | FIELD | VALUE | Rnk
> -: | :---- | ----: | --:
>  1 | A     |     1 |   1
>  2 | B     |     3 |   1
>  3 | C     |     5 |   1
>  4 | A     |    90 |   2
>  5 | B     |    15 |   2
>  6 | C     |    21 |   2
>  7 | A     |    31 |   3
>  8 | B     |    75 |   3
>  9 | C     |    82 |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=68f48f680e59f75960420afb57301691)*